# Flex function unput(int cahr), In JFlex the same function

Tags: flex-lexer, jflex

We know that in C Flex there is a function unput(int c) which can put the character c back onto the input stream, I wonder if there is a similar function in JFlex. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the specification of `unput` from a flex manual we can note its functionality:

> unput(c) puts the character c back onto the input stream. It will be
>   the next character scanned. The following action will take the current
>   token and cause it to be rescanned enclosed in parentheses.
>
> ```
> {
> int i;
> /* Copy yytext because unput() trashes yytext */
> char *yycopy = strdup( yytext );
> unput( ')' );
> for ( i = yyleng - 1; i >= 0; --i )
>     unput( yycopy[i] );
> unput( '(' );
> free( yycopy );
> }
> ```
>
> Note that since each unput() puts the given character back at the beginning of the input stream, pushing back strings must be done
>   back-to-front.

According to the [JFlex manual](http://jflex.de/manual.pdf), there is no `unput`, but there is `yypushback`:

> • `void yypushback(int number)`
>
> pushes number characters of the matched text back into the input
>   stream. They will be read again in the next call of the scanning
>   method. The number of characters to be read again must not be greater
>   than the length of the matched text. The pushed back characters will
>   not be included in `yylength()` and `yytext()`. Note that in Java
>   strings are unchangeable, i.e. an action code like
>
> ```
> String matched = yytext();
> yypushback(1);
> return matched;
> ```
>
> will return the whole matched text, while
>
> ```
> yypushback(1);
> return yytext();
> ```
>
> will return the matched text minus the last character.

Although they are not the same, many of the uses of unput can be achieved by using `yypushback`; however you cannot put different characters into the input stream, which you could with `unput`. Note that flex has `yyless` which operates like `yypushback`.